# Hadoop: Error in implementing Bayesian Algorithm in Apache Mahout

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, mahout, bayesian

I have a problem with executing the Bayesian algorithm in Mahout. I built it with Maven and the job file is in the target directory. When run from the terminal using Hadoop, I'm getting the ClassNotFoundException error. What should be done?

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar mahout-core-0.3-SNAPSHOT.job org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.mapreduce.bayes.bayesdriver -i test -o output
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.mapreduce.bayes.bayesdriver    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be calling:

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar mahout-core-0.3-SNAPSHOT.job org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.mapreduce.bayes.BayesDriver -i test -o output`

Note BayesDriver, not bayesdriver.

(referred to [this documentation](http://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/bayesian-commandline.html))

Comment: Well, guess it should be in lowercase only. It has worked with other programs using MapReduce without Mahout. In any case I tried that which is not making any difference.

Comment: This is the error which I get when I give BayesDriver.


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.mapreduce.bayes.BayesDriver.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:150)

Answer (score 0):

Is the fact that your file ends with a .job instead of a .jar relevant? The documentation si unclear.